# How can I add all kernels/filters in a single TensorFlow Layer and give output as 1 final single image?

Tags: image, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow2.0, convolution

What I need to do is I have a final layer in my model as (None,512,512,64) , I want to add all these 64 images element wise and give output from my model.
So How can I add all the images present in a single layer leading to 1 output.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your current network has the following layer:

```
layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(9, 9), input_shape=(512, 512, 1), padding='same',name = 'conv1')(input)
```

Now your feature has dimension [None, 512, 512, 64]. You can follow it up with

```
layer = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(9, 9), input_shape=(512, 512, 1), padding='same',name = 'conv2')(input)
```

I assume you are using Conv2D, so your output will be a grayscale image of shape `[None, 512, 512, 1]`. If this is not what you want and you simply want to add the tensors, you can use `tf.math.reduce_sum` across `axis = 3`, just feed it the tensor output of first layer.